# read properties from third party jar in spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot

I’m adding a third party jar as a maven dependency in my spring boot application A. Third party jar is a jar of another spring-boot application B. it has its own configurations saved in conf folder "B.properties".

I have used @Import({B.class}) annotation to import the beans of application B in my application but not able to access the configuration properties of application B. Is there any way to access the configuration properties of an application from a jar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own Config Server just add @EnableConfigServer annotation and provider configurations from service A to service B.
You can review this example:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/centralized-configuration/

**UPDATED** Fix adding

```
@PropertySource("classpath:/conf/B.properties"),
```

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, we are using consul for storing the configurations. Service A works fine after adding service B configurations to service A application.yml but i was looking for a way to load the B's configurations from jar using any spring annotation or component scan if possible.

Comment: Something like this @PropertySource("file:/yourPath/application.properties")?

Comment: adding @PropertySource("file:/conf/B.properties") does not work for me. B.properties is located in conf directory of application B.

Comment: It works with @PropertySource("classpath:/conf/B.properties"), i missed to add leading "/" before conf. configuration files in located under /conf folder inside jar.

Comment: Cool, so I'm going to edit this answer based on that solution. kind regards.